# android - how to get location update on every 10 meters?

Tags: android, location

in my application i have to update specific data on travelling of each 10 meters. 
For that i m  using LocationManager to get updates , but i am not getting correct answers.

I have used following code : Also added Permissions coarse, fine , internet .

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(getProviderName(), 10000,
            10, locationListener);

private String getProviderName() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    // criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_MEDIUM);
    criteria.setSpeedAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_MEDIUM);
    criteria.setBearingAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_MEDIUM);

    return locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
}
```

Is this condition says LocationManager to update on every 10 seconds for 10 meters covered or not? am i right?

Comment: Ckeck this Example and Slove Problem http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: I need location update for every 10 meters..